# Using tastypie filters with angularjs and restangular

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, tastypie, restangular

I am trying to use AngularJS + [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) to interact with an API created in Django with Tastypie. I have successfully interacted with the API using [example code found here](http://www.re-cycledair.com/using-restangular-with-django-tastypie) as a starting point (shown below).

```
yourApp.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("/api");
    RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation, what, url) {
        var newResponse;
        if (operation === "getList") {
            newResponse = response.objects;
            newResponse.metadata = response.meta;
        } else {
            newResponse = response;
        }
        return newResponse;
    });
    RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('/?');
});
```

I would like to use Tastypie's filtering mechanism in my API calls, but these parameters are sent via the query string and not the URI. An example from the [Tastypie docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html): http://localhost:8000/api/v1/entry/?user__username=daniel

Apart from reconfiguring Restangular's setRequestSuffix option before each request, is there any clean way to apply Tastypie-style filters in the query string using Restangular?

Comment: What if you use POST instead of GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/301#issuecomment-24273429

```
// GET to /partners?where={agentID: 1}
Restangular.all('partners').getList({where: '{agentID: 1}'});

// GET to /partners/123?where={agentID: 1}
Restangular.one('partners', 123).get({where: '{agentID: 1}'});
```

Seems like the getList() does the trick here.